# Не могу отправить два прикрепленных файла с разных input-ов phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Вот код для отправки письма:

```php
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
$message = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
    return $string;
}
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";

try 
{
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $user_photo = 'uploads/' . $_FILES["photo_scan"]["photo"];
        $user_passport_scan = 'uploads/' . $_FILES["passport_scan"]["passport"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo_scan"]["photo"], $user_photo);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["passport_scan"]["passport"], $user_passport_scan);

        $message = '
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
            <h3 align="center">Заявка с сайта tulpantravel.ru</h3>
            <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%">ФИО</td>
                    <td width="70%">' . $_POST["user_fullname"] . '</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%">Пол</td>
                    <td width="70%">' . $_POST['user_gender'] . '</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%">Номер телефона</td>
                    <td width="70%">' . $_POST["user_phone"] . '</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%">Электронная почта</td>
                    <td width="70%">' . $_POST["user_email"] . '</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%">Место работы</td>
                    <td width="70%">' . $_POST["user_workplace"] . '</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        ';
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';
        $mail->Port = '465';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = '***********************';
        $mail->Password = '************************';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->From = '******************************';
        $mail->FromName = '***********';
        $mail->AddAddress('************', '******');
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->AddAttachment($user_photo);
        $mail->AddAttachment($user_passport_scan);
        $mail->Subject = 'Заявка с сайта';
        $mail->Body = $message;
        if($mail->Send())
        {
            $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Заявка успешно отправлена</div>';
            unlink($user_photo);
            unlink($user_passport_scan);
        }
        else
        {
            $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Произошла ошибка при отправке заявки</div>';
        }
    }
} 
catch (Exception $error)
{
    echo 'Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

}
finally
{
    header('location: ../../../../index.php');
}
```

Вот форма:

```html
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/template-parts/mail.php'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>ФИО</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_fullname" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Пол</label>
            <select name="user_gender" class="form-control">
                <option value="Мужской">Мужской</option>
                <option value="Женский">Женский</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Номер телефона</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_phone" class="form-control" pattern="\d*" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Эл. почта</label>
            <input type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Место работы</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_workplace" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Загрузить фото</label>
            <input type="file" name="photo_scan" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Загрузить скан паспорта</label>
            <input type="file" name="passport_scan" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить заявку" class="btn btn-info" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Проблема заключается в том что данные с текстовых полей отправляются и отображаются в письме, но прикрепленные файле нет, будто их вообще не отправляли, уже два дня сижу ничего в голову не приходит, много гуглил но толку от этого не стало

Comment: Файлы попадают на сервер?

Comment: @ArchDemon пока код запускаю только в openserver, но если вы про то попадают ли они в `uploads/` то нет

Comment: Закомментируйте строки `unlink($user_photo);`  `unlink($user_passport_scan);` и посмотрите что файлы действительно сохраняются на сервере

Comment: @ArchDemon только это делал, как прилетел коммент, нет не сохраняются

Comment: Проблема значит не в отправке письма, а в загрузке файлов на сервер. Смотрите логи. Проверяйте что возвращает `move_uploaded_file()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменить:

```php
$user_photo = 'uploads/' . $_FILES["photo_scan"]["photo"];
$user_passport_scan = 'uploads/' . $_FILES["passport_scan"]["passport"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo_scan"]["photo"], $user_photo);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["passport_scan"]["passport"], $user_passport_scan);
```

На:

```php
$user_photo = 'uploads/' . $_FILES["photo_scan"]["name"];
$user_passport_scan = 'uploads/' . $_FILES["passport_scan"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo_scan"]["tmp_name"], $user_photo);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["passport_scan"]["tmp_name"], $user_passport_scan);
```